# How to hide intermediate URL using nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Let's say I have a website with domain abc.com and wish that users accessing it should be redirected to abcd.com using nginx. The webapp should not see the abc.com at all. Is that possible?

```
server {
    server_name abc.com www.abc.com;
    location / {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://www.gmail.com$request_uri present;
    }
}
```

The above code does redirect the users from abc.com to gmail.com, but the problem is that for the physical webapp, the URL shown is still abc.com. I would like the url to be https://www.gmail.com.

Question: Can I somehow hide this middle URL abc.com entirely to third party apps like physical web?

Comment: What do you mean by third party webapps?

Comment: third party app example: google physical web.